# Convergence in probability of r.v. with $f_{X_n}(x)=\frac{n}{2} e^{-n|x|}$

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ be a sequence of continuous random variables for which holds
> $$
> f_{X_n}(x)=\frac{n}{2} e^{-n|x|} .
> $$
> Show that $X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

_

I got this far: We have to prove that for every $\varepsilon>0 $ it holds that
$$ 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n-0|\geq \varepsilon) = 0.
$$
This gives
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\geq \varepsilon)=1-\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\leq \varepsilon)=1-\mathbb{P}(-\varepsilon\leq X_n\leq \varepsilon)=1-\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} \frac{n}{2} e^{-n|x|} dx=1-\left[\dfrac{x\cdot\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-n\left|x\right|}\right)}{2\left|x\right|}\right]_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon.
$$
I am not sure if this is the right way and how to continue? Any hints?

Comment: I am unsure how you missed the obvious way: $\displaystyle \int\limits_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon \frac{n}{2} e^{-n |x|} dx = \int\limits_0^\varepsilon n e^{-n x} dx = 1 - e^{-nx}.$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $X_n \sim \text{Laplace}(\mu = 0, b = 1/n)$ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Probability_density_function)). Thus $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$ and $$\text{Var}(X_n) = 2\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^2 = \dfrac{2}{n^2}\text{.}$$
By the [Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Chebyshev%27s_inequality), letting $\epsilon > 0$,
$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq \epsilon) \leq \dfrac{2}{n^2\epsilon}\text{.}$$
Observing that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq \epsilon) \geq 0$ since we are working with a probability, taking $n \to \infty$, and applying the squeeze theorem, we get the desired value of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use characteristic functions and their properties. One can show that $\phi_n(t) = \frac{n^2}{n^2+t^2}$. Noting uniform continuity of $\phi$, we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\phi_n(t) = 1$ which is the characteristic function of the random variable that takes the value $0$ a.s.